# PHP in Javascript using Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have found a few articles about using PHP in JS but nothing has helped me so far, so here is my question. I need to call wordpress post content (title, excerpt and thumbnail) into a JS "preview" functionality (essentially calling posts with the [ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/)). I have been able to make the "expanding preview" open from the post thumbnail and title, however I am having trouble adding the post content to the preview.

I am attempting to add the php calls to the preview function in the "grid.js" file, however I am not sure exactly how to "minify" the php code. See below for my code.

**The code as it reads originally:**

```
this.$title = $( '<h3></h3>' );
```

**And here is how I am attempting to call the post title:**

```
this.$title = $( '<h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>' );
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this in the grid.js file?

Comment: It sure is.. In the preview function:

Comment: By default your server isn't going to parse php in a js file... only in .php files

Comment: @user2105735: PHP doesn't work by itself on any extension. A JS file won't (by default) be parsed by PHP on most hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys. Not to be needy but any ideas how I would go about doing this if not within the JS file?

Answer (score 4):

Some clarifications: PHP is a server side language; this means that it can be parsed and executed only server-side.
That said, you have two options here, one more elegant, the other a bit crappy (i would use it only in really rare and limited cases):

1. Elegant solution: Wordpress Ajax. Setup an ajax-callable function in your functions.php file which returns data-populated html:

   a. Add an ajax-callable action to your functions.php file:

   ```
   add_action("wp_ajax_[function_name]", "function_name");
   //If the action wants users to be logged in, you can specify a different function to be called in case a user is not:
   //add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_[function_name]", "[function_name_for_non_logged_users]");
   ```

   b. Specify the function to be called (specify a second one for non logged-in users in case you need it)

   ```
   function function_name() {
     //It is good practice to use nonce verification
     if (!wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "function_name_nonce")) {
       exit("[Your scary message against bad people]");
     }

     // Make your query here.
     $post_id = $_REQUEST["post_id"];
     $post = get_post($id, ARRAY_A);

     // Return your data. Here I go with a simple JSON.
     $result = json_encode($result);
     echo $result;
   }
   ```

   c. Cook the frontend-code, somewhere in the template (obviously make it so that's available to your grid.js calls). You'll need to have $post populated with your post data. I tend to use a global wrapper:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       <?php 
       $nonce = wp_create_nonce('function_name_nonce');
       $endpoint = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
       ?>
       var Globals = {
         nonce: "<?php echo $nonce; ?>", 
         postId: "<?php echo $post->ID; ?>", 
         endpoint: "<?php echo $endpoint; ?>"
       }
   </script>
   ```

   d. From now on, it's up to you to make the ajax call (I don't have any references to your code) but it's pretty straightforward:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: "post",
     dataType: "json",
     url: Globals.endpoint,
     data: {
       action: "function_name", 
       post_id: Globals.postId, 
       nonce: Globals.nonce
     },
     success: function(response) {
       //Aaaaand here's your post data
       console.log(response);
     }
   });
   ```

   See http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action) for this.

   This is a good tutorial (found it on the first page of Google): http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/
2. Crappy solution: generated data-populated JS code (i would stick to a JS object). In this case, you will need an additional script tag inside your page (template or whatever else has access to PHP) in which you'll output JS valid code:

   ```
   var title = "<?php the_title(); ?>";
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will give these solutions a try. All help has been and is very appreciated!

Comment: Thanks again for your help, however Im still struggling over this. I've added your JS in my template file and tried a few different variations to no success. Do I need to add anything additional in order for it to communicate to the grid.js file?

Comment: Phew, wrote an articulated version of the elegant solution. I could have mistyped something, try and let me know, I'll recheck.

Comment: REALLY appreciate all your help so far. I will try to implement your solution to my best ability. Will keep you updated with my progress. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Well, I've really been researching and trying to implement your "elegant" solution unfortunately to no success. Being more of a noob I'm leaning toward your JS object solution.. 

I can output my object's string to the page using your code, I'm just not sure how to output it into my expanded div (created by the grid.js) file.. I hate to be so needy, but I've been banging my head over this for a couple of days now. :/ Could you possibly provide more isight on how to accomplish this using the JS object method? Again, REALLY appreciate all your help thus far and any future help!

Comment: @user2105735 You're welcome, don't worry! I continue to suggest the "elegant" one, for these reasons: a) you probably have a lot of posts in the page. Loading all of their data in-page, throw it into a big js object, and then use it through grid.js is memory expensive; b) It's even worse if you want to show large post images (since they should be loaded all one-shot at page load) and c) Ajax forces you to have a callback-ed approach, which helps putting loading animations and cool stuff like that, and makes everything work better. I'll put up a simple Github for you (need some time though).

Comment: Super appreciated! I will scrap the JS and continue my efforts in the meantime of your github. Oh, and if it helps, my link that I am attempting to apply these is below (I may be working on it if it looks wonky!) http://ddp.l3mdev.com/test/

Comment: So I've actually been able to somewhat fill the elements just by using the "data variables" just like the tutorial. However, when I add the "excerpt" and thumbnail php it seems to be causing things to get a bit wonky (you can see my code). Any ideas why this might be causing this or do these just have to be populated from the function you are talking about? '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-og-grid" data-title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"  data-description="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>" data-largesrc="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>'

Comment: Well, I've been able to solve the wonkiness by simply changing my double quotes to single quotes on the data-description and data-largesrc, however I am still not able to get the thumbnail to display within the "preview inner" div. I have tried a few variations of the thumbnail php and moved the end if below the link as well but no luck. Again, thanks for all your help on this so far. I assume I just have something just off but I don't think we'll need a function necessarily. Any ideas on why my thumb doesn't want to come through?

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the html output? What's getting rendered?

Comment: Just the image loader if I try to call the post thumbnail. It does work if I call a static image though so I think its something with my thumbnail call somehow.

Comment: As i remember, the_post_thumbnail returns a full img tag. So in your case i think it would be better to only get the image url, put it in the data-largesrc, and then populate an image tag with it from your js script.

Comment: :/ can you give me an example?

Comment: I was able to execute it by a custom if statement and '<?php echo $image[0]; ?>', however of course now a couple of the post titles have disappeared. :/ Argh!

Comment: It seems that for the posts that dont have thumbnails the IF statement is causing the titles to disappear.

Comment: Well I believe I've been able to hack my way through my questions as of now. Again, really appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: OK, I might put my foot in my mouth here and try to get more of your help! :/ Wondering if you have any ideas why on my page when you apply a filter to the posts (for example, click on "Downtown News" it will filter only the posts from that category) why the preview functionality stops working? I was really hoping to figure this one out on my own but I've spent countless hours down the rabbit hole debugging that and any insight would also be greatly appreciated, as always. Thanks again for all your help!